# QGIS simplify geometries shifts polygons north

Tags: qgis, simplify

I'm trying to simplify polygons in a shapefile using the "Simplify Geometries" tool in QGIS 2.10 (Pisa). This works as expected, except for one strange effect: the resulting features (shown in green) are slightly shifted to the north:

[image]
How can I avoid this?

Comment: does the pre-processed shp have a defined CRS?

Comment: @artwork21: it did not, and this was the problem. Care to make that the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my comment noted, make sure you define your layers CRS before running the Simplify Geometries tool to avoid feature shift.